# Can java stored procedures in Oracle 12c validate an xml against a schema with "redefine" and "import"?

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle12c, xsd-validation, java-stored-procedures

I am generating an xml within the database and need to validate it within the database against a set of 7 xsds (one main xsd, 2 getting imported by the main xsd, 1 redefined in the main xsd and 3 more being imported within others). 
I tried registering the schemas into XDB and was able to register 6 schemas but the main one as it has "redefine" and xdb doesnt support registering a schema with "redefine".
[Failure to register main schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgEwN.png)

Now i want to try using XML Schema Processor for Java to validate the xml by creating a java stored procedure as described at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96621/adx22spp.htm

I want to know if this approach using xml schema processer for java will work for my problem of multiple schemas with import and redefine.

If yes, what different will i need to do from what oracle explains in the link?

Comment: What is "the database"? You seem to be asking about a specific product, please name it and tag it.

Comment: It's Oracle Database 12c Release 1.